# How to remake a request under query builder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

Please, help me!

How i can remake this request under query builder. Doctrine2

```
    SELECT *
FROM orders AS o
  INNER JOIN states AS s ON o.OrderId = s.orderID

WHERE o.partnerId = 52 AND
      (s.state = 'CANCEL' OR s.state = 'FINISH') AND
      (s.dt BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-10-30 00:00:00')
```

Orders

```
class Order
{
/**
     * @var State[] $states
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="State", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist"})
     * @OrderBy({"dt" = "DESC"})
     */
    protected $states;
}
```

States

```
class State
{

    public function __construct($state = null)
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $orderId;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $dt;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="enum('NEW','REGIST','SENTTOSHOP','ARRIVEDTOSHOP','FINISH','CANCEL','RETURNEDTOSTORAGE')")
     */
    protected $state;



    /**
     * @var $order
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Zabberi\Order", inversedBy="states")
     * @JoinColumn(name="orderId", referencedColumnName="OrderId")
     */
    protected $order;
}
```

Sorry if I did not understand you.

Some text... |  It provides a set of classes and methods that is able to programmatically build queries, and also provides a fluent API. This means that you can change between one methodology to the other as you want, or just pick a preferred one.>

Comment: Provide your entity definitions for orders entity and states entity

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid hello! I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your query using query builder as

```
 $qb = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Order');
 $qb->createQueryBuilder('o')
    ->select('o,s')
    ->join('o.states','s')
    ->where("s.state IN(:states)")
    ->andWhere('s.dt BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2')
   ->setParameter('states', array('CANCEL','FINISH'))
   ->setParameter('date1', '2017-01-01 00:00:00')
   ->setParameter('date2', '2017-10-30 00:00:00')
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult()
   ;
```

Comment: Dear friend, I am very grateful! God himself sent you.